# Get all bounds lengths from PDB

Tags: python, biopython, pdb-files

I want to get all bounds lengths from PDB file.

I tried `Bio.PDB`, but I don't understand `NeighborSearch` class and it's methods: `search()` and `search_all()`

```py
from Bio.PDB import *
import numpy as np

structure = PDBParser().get_structure('Kek', '1wba.pdb')

atom_list = [_ for _ in structure.get_atoms()]

kek = NeighborSearch(atom_list).search_all(2)

for atom_pair in kek:
    a = atom_pair[0]
    b = atom_pair[1]
    distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(a.coord) - np.array(b.coord))
    print(distance)
```

How can I solve my task? Maybe there's another framework - I'll watch every variant if it works right!

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to find all atoms within a certain distance of a target atom? And do the same for all other atoms?

Comment: @fzn no, no. I want to get list with pairs of atoms, which connected!

Comment: Oh cool. So look at my answer below. You can adjust the `_cutoff_dist` to be whatever you think would be an appropriate bond-length.  `close_atoms` would then contain list of potentially connected atoms. This should somewhat solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are looking to find ways to calculate the distance between atoms in a PDB file. I adapted your answer and [this](https://www.biostars.org/p/269579/) Biostars solution. Hope it helps a bit

```py
import Bio.PDB

parser = Bio.PDB.PDBParser(QUIET=True)
structures = parser.get_structure('2rdx', '2rdx.pdb')
structure = structures[0]
atom_list = [_ for _ in structure.get_atoms()]

ns = Bio.PDB.NeighborSearch(atom_list)
_cutoff_dist = 5

for target in atom_list:
  close_atoms = ns.search(target.coord, _cutoff_dist)
  for close_atom in close_atoms:
    print(target, close_atom, target - close_atom)
  print ("==========")
```

You can easily find distance between two Atom objects by using the `-` operator.

Comment: Is `NeighborSearch` really finding atoms, that have bonds, or it isn't?

Comment: NeighborSearch is a special class to make it easy to search for neighbour `atoms/residues/chains/models/structures`, etc. 

Refer this for more:
https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.NeighborSearch%27-pysrc.html#NeighborSearch

Comment: PDB may not necessarily contain info about whether a nearby atom is bonded with the atom. You would have to use the bond distance heuristic, e.g. Carbon with Oxygen atoms within 1.5A probably has a bond between them.